# curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh fails

Tags: rust, rustup

I have tried installing everything for substrate and got to this point. I cannot understand how or why I am having problems here.

I am running on Windows 10 and everything seems to have gone fine up until now.

```
curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh
source ~/.cargo/enventer code here
```

The error returned is:

```
sh : The term 'sh' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:2 char:34
+ curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh
+                                  ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (sh:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

source : The term 'source' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:4 char:1
+ source ~/.cargo/env
+ ~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (source:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: You cannot run `sh` scripts in Vanilla Windows. You need to either use WSL or use a different way of installing rust.

Comment: As @apopiak says, you cannot run that script directly on Windows, you can work with WSL without problems or follow the getting started on Windows guide if you definitely want to work on Windows https://substrate.dev/docs/en/knowledgebase/getting-started/windows-users

Comment: Like others said, you cant sun sh scripts in windows, you can find install instructions for rust here: https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install